# Run Windows application on Build Server by TFS Release Build Definition

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild, build-definition, vnext

Run  notepad or any  other windows application  with  Release Definition on  build server   using  powershell  or batch scripts:
I tried all the commands known to me:

```
& ′notepad.exe′
Invoke-Expression -Command ′notepad.exe′
Start-Process -FilePath ′notepad.exe′
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start(′notepad.exe′)
([wmiclass]″Win32_Process″).Create(′notepad.exe′)
Invoke-WmiMethod -Class Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList ″notepad.exe″
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& notepad.exe′}
cmd /c ″notepad.exe″
```

When running on the server itself everything works(start  notepad  or any  onther win  app)
but
When i tried running by TFS Release Definition : Command end successful but  on  build  server - nothing happens.

Any Ideas!!!

Comment: How are you making the determination that nothing happens?  If you're logged into the build server but notepad is opened by the user the build/release process executes as, you're not going to see it.

Comment: I check  in  my  Build  Server  an  i  want  see  Notepad is  open  ... in fact, nothing happens there, just in Task  Manager  i  can  see  in  Background  processes something  running ... But I do not want to see in the processes, I want to start notepad remotely through TFS Release Defenitions!

Comment: Notepad is a bad choice as it's a GUI application. What is your **actual** goal?

Comment: actual Goal it’s run GUI applications it was for this purpose that the Notepad (for example)

Answer (score 0):

If your agent runs in interactive mode and all the other settings are configured correctly, then the answer is that the command works. But the issue is that all the launched process will be closed as soon as the build/release is finished.So you didn't see the launched app when check it. To verify this, add a powershell script task with following command:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe' -wait
```

Run the release and check on server, you should see notepad is opened. However, this command will cause the release never finish until you close the notepad.